# Modifying chemmacros arrow labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig, chemmacros

How can I recreate the following image? I tried using the `chemmacros` package, but it doesn't seem to work all the way. Please let me know.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\begin{document}
\schemestart[0,1,{black}] 
\OX{a,g} \arrow \OX{b,mol} \arrow \OX{c,mol} \arrow \OX{d,g}
\redox(a,b)[-stealth,thick][-4]{$M$ of limiting reagent}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may well be more elegant options but this seems to work.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\begin{document}
\schemestart[0,1,{black}] 
\OX{a,g} \arrow \OX{b,mol} \arrow \OX{c,mol} \arrow \OX{d,g}
\redox(a,b)[-stealth,thick][-4]{\raisebox{-3pt}{\smash{\begin{tabular}{c}
\strut$M$ of\\ limiting reagent\end{tabular}}}}
\redox(b,c)[-stealth,thick][4]{stoichiometry}
\redox(c,d)[-stealth,thick][-4]{\raisebox{-3pt}{\smash{\begin{tabular}{c}
\strut$M$ of\\ product\end{tabular}}}}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]